# C# razor object is not defined on click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following code in my index.cshtml where a **FoursquareInfo** object is beeing created.

```
@using WebMatrix.Data;
@using CanYouPay.Models.FoursquareAPI;
@{
    FoursquareInfo fsInfo = new FoursquareInfo();
    Checkins response = new Checkins();
    Checkin checkins = new Checkin();
    List<RootItem> items = new List<RootItem>();
    RootItem item = new RootItem();
    Venue venue = new Venue();
    Location loc = new Location();
    loc.lat = 51.19189444478925;
    loc.lng = 4.664656084372357;

    venue.location = loc;
    item.venue = venue;
    items.Add(item);
    checkins.items = items;
    response.checkins = checkins;
    fsInfo.response = response;
}
```

I have a div in my html code for the index.cshtml where the `updateMap(fourSquareInfo)` method is called when clicked.

```
<div id="mapBtn" onclick="updateMap(@fsInfo)" class="btn btn-success btn-lg col-md-2 pull-right">Show Map!</div>
```

My `updateMap` function is:

```
function updateMap(foursquareInfo) {
    var uluru = { lat: 20, lng: 30 };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: uluru,
        map: map
    });
}
```

Yes, for testing purposes I don't do anything with the `foursquareInfo` object passed - the `lat` and `long` values will be replaced by the `foursquareInfo` ones when I can fix the error I receive when the `onClick` event happens:

**CanYouPay is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick**[image]

What is wrong with my html/razor/js code?

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, i am not getting what error you get on click method.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to pass a c# object into your js - if you view source on that button, it is probably going to be some text including `CanYouPay` and as you have not defined it as a js variable, it will throw an error, you would either need to create a js object and map your c# object values to it, or pass through a bunch of strings

Comment: @Pete mmh that is possible

Comment: @Pete do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: I'll add an answer

Comment: That would be very nice!

Answer (score 2):

As per my comments: Looks like you are trying to pass a c# object into your js - if you view source on that button, it is probably going to be some text including CanYouPay and as you have not defined it as a js variable, it will throw an error, you would either need to create a js object and map your c# object values to it, or pass through a bunch of strings

Option 1 create a js object that matches your c# object and in your razor you can map the values:

```js
<script>
   // this needs to be in your razor before the onclick (so object is created before you use it)
   var fsJSObject = new fsJSObject(); // this object should match your c# object
   fsJSObject.StringValue = '@fsInfo.StringValue'; // this needs to be the final value - eg a string, int, date, etc - cannot be another object, otherwise you will get a similar mistake to above
   fsJSObject.IntValue= @fsInfo.IntValue;

  // pass fsJSObject into your onclick function
</script>
```

Option 2, pass the values directly into the function

```
onclick="updateMap('@fsInfo.StringValue', @fsInfo.IntValue, '@fsInfo.AnotherStringValue')"
```

Notice the quotes around the string values

Comment: Using a JSON library to convert the c# object to JSON which is easy to handle in JS might be a good option.

Comment: @Smut: Also for some additional context of why this does what it does when you do `@fsInfo` it will call `ToString` on that object to get a string that can be put into the page. If you haven't overridden the default `ToString` implementation it will output the classname instead which I assume is `CanYouPay.Models.FoursquareAPI.FoursquareInfo`. JS will then of course try to treat that as a JS expression which will lead to it concluding that it can't find `CanYouPay`.

Comment: @Smut to go with chris's first comment I usually nuget install newtonsoft json package for deserialising and serialising my c# to json

Answer (score 1):

When I try to build up the same page using razor I see I get the following in my page:

```
<div id="mapBtn" onclick="updateMap(WebApplication1.Models.FoursquareInfo)" class="btn btn-success btn-lg col-md-2 pull-right">Show Map!< /div>
```

As you see Razor will directly set the object which is to say the class name. In this case, I would advise to directly set the location numbers in the call like:

```
<div id="mapBtn" onclick="updateMap(@loc.lat, @loc.lng)" class="btn btn-success btn-lg col-md-2 pull-right">Show Map!< /div>
```

And then in the call on the server side build up the object and do what you want with it. Remember you'll have to rebuild the object every time you do a new call to the server: the objects are not kept in memory. It is advised to only put the information in the view that view actually needs instead of your entire serverside object.